Unresolved reference: categories. the ide does not highlight it in red and does not mark it in any way
I have an interface for getting a category of dishes
interface MealService {
    @GET("categories.php")
    suspend fun getMeal(): MealCategoriesDto
}

and data class
data class MealCategories(
    val categories: List<Category>
)

UseCase
class GetMealUseCase @Inject constructor(private val mealRepository: MealRepository) {
    suspend operator fun invoke() = mealRepository.getMeal()
}

repoImpl
class MealRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val service: MealService
) : MealRepository {
    override suspend fun getMeal(): Flow<Request<MealCategories>> {
        return RequestUtils.requestFlow {
            val response = service.getMeal()
            response.toDomain()
        }
    }
}

MainUiState
data class MainUiState(
    val loadState: LoadState = LoadState.SUCCESS,
    val categoriesMain: List<Category> = emptyList(),
    val error: String? = null
)

VM
@HiltViewModel
class MainFragmentViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val getMealUseCase: GetMealUseCase
) : ViewModel() {
    private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(MainUiState())
    val uiState: StateFlow<MainUiState>
        get() = _uiState.asStateFlow()

    init {
        fetchMeals()
    }

    private fun fetchMeals() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            getMealUseCase.invoke().collect { request ->
                when (request) {
                    is Request.Loading -> {
                        _uiState.update { it.copy(loadState = LoadState.LOADING) }
                    }

                    is Request.Success -> {
                        val result = request.data.categories
                        _uiState.update {
                            it.copy(
                                loadState = LoadState.SUCCESS,
                                categoriesMain = result
                            )
                        }
                    }

                    is Request.Error -> {
                        _uiState.update {
                            it.copy(
                                loadState = LoadState.ERROR,
                                error = request.error!!.message
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

error in line: val result = request.data.categories
e: Unresolved reference: categories
I don't understand why this error is and how to fix it.
I've checked all the possible options
->Invalid cache and restart
->rename name categories:List

Can you also provide code for your Request class?

@Yamin
sealed class Request<T> {     class Loading<T> : Request<T>()     data class Success<T>(internal val data: T) : Request<T>()     data class Error<T>(internal val error: Throwable?) : Request<T>() }

Decision:
Commented out the code that caused the error
Launched the project
I commented out the code again and started it again
The error has disappeared
